# Azure storage - How does blob versioning affect listing operations?

Tags: azure-storage

From [microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/versioning-overview#pricing-and-billing), it seems that too many versions will affect the speed of listing operations.

> Enabling versioning for data that is frequently overwritten may result in increased storage capacity charges and increased latency during listing operations. To mitigate these concerns, store frequently overwritten data in a separate storage account with versioning disabled.

Will creating a new version do a list operation, or lock something?

---

what SumanthMarigowda-MSFT said may be [List Blobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/list-blobs):

> include={snapshots,metadata,uncommittedblobs,copy,deleted,tags,versions,
> deletedwithversions,immutabilitypolicy,legalhold,permissions}
>
> Optional. Specifies one or more datasets to include in the response:
>
> -versions: Version 2019-12-12 and newer. Specifies that Versions of blobs should be included in the enumeration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a new version does not perform a listing operation, or lock anything. It's just that if you're making lots of updates to a blob, you're going to be creating lots of versions.

More versions means increased capacity charges. And more versions means longer listing times when you list blobs and include versions.